# why is mySQL missing a column?

Tags: mysql

This statement is not populating the image_path column. I have copied and pasted column names from phpMyAdmin to ensure accuracy.

```
INSERT INTO (theme_name, theme_path, image_path)
VALUES ('',
        '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/waggleb/wp-content/plugins/app-switcher/themes/Original/',
        '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/waggleb/wp-content/plugins/app-switcher/thumbnails/original.png')
```

Comment: Can you give some details on that column?  What type is it?  My first thought is that you might have tried to insert a string that is too long for the column (if its of type varchar).

Comment: You mean that a new row is successfully inserted but the image_path column of the inserted row is NULL?

Comment: What table are you inserting this into?  And why are you specifying theme_name if you are inserting an empty string for it?

Comment: What do you mean by _not populating_?

Comment: Does it not return an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing the table name.

It should be:

Insert Into [Table_name]
([Columns])
Values ([Values])

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a table name. If you look at the [MySQL INSERT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), you'll see that it's mandatory to include a table name.

As such, if you alter your query to become..

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE NAME> (theme_name, theme_path, image_path) VALUES...
```

...all should be well.

Answer (score 3):

you missed the table name

```
INSERT INTO  TABLENAME(theme_name, theme_path, image_path)
VALUES ('',
        '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/waggleb/wp-content/plugins/app-switcher/themes/Original/',
        '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/waggleb/wp-content/plugins/app-switcher/thumbnails/original.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to name a table to INSERT into:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (theme_name, theme_path, image_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you omitted the table name on purpopse, check that the datatypes are correct for the columns. Check lengths of target columns are long enough to hold what you are inserting.